# Scroll a UIViewController to the top just like it is done when clicking on the iOS Status Bar

Tags: ios, tableview, scrollview

I would like to know if the method that Apple uses to scroll a `UIViewController` that contains a `UIScrollView` to the top when the user taps on the status bar is available to us.

I tried to find it, but I had no success.

I tried to reproduce it, but it did not work 100% when the `UIViewController` prefers to display large title (the large title is not expanded).

How can we scroll a `UIViewController` to the top just like Apple does?

---

Follows my trial:

```
extension UIViewController {

    private var firstScrollView: UIScrollView? {
        var scrollView: UIScrollView? = nil

        var viewsToCheck = [self.view]
        while !viewsToCheck.isEmpty && scrollView == nil {
            let viewToCheck = viewsToCheck.remove(at: 0)!

            if let viewToCheckAsScrollView = viewToCheck as? UIScrollView {
                scrollView = viewToCheckAsScrollView
            } else {
                viewsToCheck.append(contentsOf: viewToCheck.subviews)
            }
        }

        return scrollView
    }

    func scrollToTheTop(animated: Bool) {
        if let firstScrollView = firstScrollView {
            firstScrollView.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1), animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The behaviour you describe is a native behaviour if you are using a UIScrollView subclass (UITableView or a UIScrollView). It's working for me without adding any additional code.

Comment: @Mourad is there any way that I can call it? I want to do it programatically.

Comment: can you please explain? when clicking on the iOS Status Bar nothing happend to me . You mean swipe down from top of status bar to see notification?

Comment: The method you are using 'scrollToTheTop' is correct. But i think that your problem is due to the implementation you are doing to get the UIScrollView instance.

I think that your while loop is not working, because the 'viewsToCheck' variable is not instantiated properly. I think that it should be initialized with self.view.subviews and not just self.view (I suppose that your UIScrollView instance is added as a subview to your UIViewController's view)

I hope this helps.

Comment: You do not explain what “but it did not work 100%“ means, so those words are meaningless. When you use your code what happens?

Comment: @matt I have edited my post just now. Not working 100% -> the large title is not expanded.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take account of the scroll view’s content inset (`adjustedContentInset`) when working out where to scroll to. Your code does not do that, so you end up scrolling to the wrong place.

```
firstScrollView.contentOffset.y = -firstScrollView.adjustedContentInset.top
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, @matt. But this code is having the same behaviour as the one that I posted. In case the UIViewController prefers to display large title, when the scrolling is done, the large title is not expanded =/.